Symfony with Svelte config doesn't generate package.json
I'm currently trying to set up a Symfony project and add Svelte to the project. On their website they claim that it's easy to add Svelte UX to the project.
I have the Symfony server running, but the node package manager can't install since there is no package.json file in the project root being generated. I ran this command:
composer require symfony/asset-mapper \
    symfony/stimulus-bundle symfony/ux-svelte

The documentation says that I should then run npm install --force and after that I could run npm run watch.
But npm install doesn't have a package.json file to run from. Should the node project be set up manually, or should the composer require command set it up for me?

Are you sure your problem is in any way directly related to Composer itself?

@NicoHaase - I mean... When they say it's: step 1) Add these things, step 2) Run it! I'd expect it to just work. They don't mention any prerequisites.

So, how is the problem related to Composer then? Is the package itself installed without any errors? Composer is not responsible for application problems. If the installation itself works, but the package is not installing everything neccessary, maybe you should report this to the maintainers of that package?

because composer is the tool I was assigned to use to handle the task, but thanks for not being helpful and I will remove the tag so you don't get bothered again. Have a good day.

According to https://symfony.com/bundles/StimulusBundle/current/index.html#how-are-the-stimulus-controllers-loaded, there's no package.json generated it you are using AssetMapper. On the other hand, https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-svelte/current/index.html tells you "This package works best with WebpackEncore", and links to another documentation for using the package using AssetMapper.  I would assume you should not follow the instructions for running with Webpack if you don't use Webpack

You use AssetMapper, so refer to using-with-asset-mapper section. The doc explain how use svelte with AssetMapper. It's necessary to compile svelte file into js file.
For your package.json run the command npm init.
In doc you can see the command npm install svelte-loader --save-dev, but this package it's used to configure webpack with svelte. And the npm run watch command use webpack/encore package to watch file change and hot loading assets. So in the doc npm command are used for webpack. I don't know if package are required to run svelte, check svelte documentation.
Composer is a php package manager and package.json manage your js package with npm (javascript package manager). So composer no alterate package.json.
I’m sorry I can’t help you more to solve your problem. I hope this information will guide you in resolving the issue.
